# How to access Kubernetes NodePort service in browser?

Tags: jenkins, service, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have created a deployment for jenkins in Kubernetes.
The pod is running fine, I've created a service to access jenkins on service-ip:8080 but it seems not to work.
When I create an `ingress` above the service I can access it using the public ip.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: jenkins-ui
  namespace: jenkins
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: jenkins
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      name: ui
```

I created my service as described above:

```
$ kubectl get svc --namespace=jenkins

NAME               TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
jenkins-ui         NodePort    10.47.xx.xx     <none>        8080:30960/TCP   1d
```

I tried to access: `10.47.xx.xx:8080` but I was not able to access the jenkins UI. What am I doing wrong? I also tried `10.47.xx.xx:30960`

I want to access my jenkins UI using a service but I want to keep it private in my cluster. (ingress makes it public).

UPDATE:

```
$ kubectl describe svc jenkins-ui --namespace jenkins
Name:                     jenkins-ui
Namespace:                jenkins
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=jenkins
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.47.xx.xx    Port:                     ui  8080/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 ui  30960/TCP
Endpoints:                10.44.10.xx:8080
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

accessing the pod on 10.44.10.xx:8080 does not work too.

Comment: Can you update your question with the response of `kubectl describe svc jenkins-ui`? I'd like to know if there are endpoints behind the service.

Comment: @fiunchinho updated

Comment: Thanks. Are you trying to connect from a pod running inside the cluster? How are making those requests?

Comment: When you create a NodePort `Service`, you should be able to access the pods running behind the service using the address public_node_ip:NodePort. So you need the public IP of one of your nodes, instead of the `Service` IP, which has an internal IP 10.47.xx.xx which will only be reachable from the same local network (the cluster).

Comment: @fiunchinho but this means that everyone on the internet can access my service? How do I keep this private?

Comment: Setting up firewalls in the nodes to only allow your local IP address (of your company offices for that matter). If you only want to access this jenkins instance for development purposes, you can always use `kubectl` builtin port forwarding https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want any container running in your cluster to be able to access your jenkins service, but you don't want your jenkins service to be accessible outside your cluster to something like your browser?

In this case:

```
curl http://jenkins-ui.default:8080
curl http://10.47.10.xx:8080
```

will work perfectly fine from ***inside any container in your kubernetes cluster***.

Also, you cannot access it `10.47.10.xx:8080` from outside your cluster because that IP is only valid/available inside your kubernetes cluster.

If you want to access it from outside the cluster an ingress controller or to connect on `http://<node-ip>: 30960` is the only way to connect to the `jenkins-ui` k8s service and thus the pod behind it.

**EDIT:** Use kubectl port-forward

In development mode, if you want to access a container running internally, you can use `kubectl port-forward`:

```
kubectl port-forward <jenkins-ui-pod> 9090:8080
```

This way, `http://localhost:9090` will show you the jenkins-ui screen because you have kubectl access.

`kubectl port-forward` doesn't work for services yet: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/15180

Comment: Thanks, yes I want to have a service (which contains a pod). I want to access the pod through the service, without using a public IP if possible, because then everyone can access my service or am I wrong? Do I have to set firewall rules everywhere (google cloud).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. How can you access your service without using a public IP? If you want to connect with your browser to a service running on the cloud, how will you connect without going through a public IP?

Comment: Is there a way to access an internal loadbalancer service in my browser?

Comment: It is now possible to port-forward to a service: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/15180#issuecomment-579257228